# How long can you wait till you add the proper yeast

Tags: yeast, wine

I crushed my  grapes added 5 lbs sugar and a wild yeast killer pectic enzyme. I haven't got the yeast for the correct grape wine process. It's been 6 days. The temperature has been maintained around 65-70°F (18-21°C). I'll be able to get my yeast in a couple of days.

Have I wasted my time or can this be saved?

Comment: There is some purple foam that collected on top of my 5 gallon ferm.

Comment: It's starting to ferment

Answer (score 3):

As long as you don't see any mold or activity of fermentation, you should be fine. You should put some sulfites in there to preserve it and kill off any wild yeast. Ideally, you should put it in the fridge or even freeze the whole thing until you are ready. Just rehydrate and pitch the yeast as soon as you get it. Hopefully, you'll see some fermentation in a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

**farmersteve** has a good answer, I just want to add some information.

This part of the process is called *[maceration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maceration_(wine))*, it is when you let the skin soak in the wine to retrieve color, tannin and flavour.  To prevent fermentation to start (the grape skin contains wild yeast) you may add sulfite and keep the temperature cold.

The "yeast killer" you used, probably contains sulfite and sorbate?  Anyhow, the effect will not last, they tend to "evaporate" in time, which explains why your wine is starting to ferment on his own.

Keep it as cold as possible and add your yeast as soon as you get it (and bring the temperature back to normal).